# How to change what Django model returns as a value?

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I'm trying to get my `Product kind` as what I declared It's name, instead I get number. Let me be more clear:
This below is my `Product Kinds`;

```
PRODUCT_KINDS = (
    ("1","Electronic"),
    ("2","Furniture"),
    ("3", "Bedroom"),
    ("4","Dining")

)
```

And this image below is my django-admin panel which everything seems perfect because I can get every single of my kinds.
[image: enter imasssge description here]

However, when I try to get this data from `api/products` url I get this data

```
[
    {
        "image": null,
        "name": "Headphones",
        "kind": "1",
        "price": 250.99,
        "description": "No description for this item.",
        "is_featured": true
    },
    {
        "image": null,
        "name": "Watch",
        "kind": "3",
        "price": 12.5,
        "description": "No description for this item.",
        "is_featured": true
    },
    {
        "image": null,
        "name": "T-shirt",
        "kind": "2",
        "price": 12.99,
        "description": "No description for this item.",
        "is_featured": true
    },
    {
        "image": null,
        "name": "Ali Ziya ÇEVİK",
        "kind": "1",
        "price": 1212.0,
        "description": "No description for this item.",
        "is_featured": false
    }
]
```

as you can see In my django-admin panel I get the name of kind but In the API I get It's index.

This below is my `serializer`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #kind = serializers.CharField(source = 'kind')
    #print(kind)
    class Meta:

        model = Product
        fields = ['image', 'name', 'kind',
                  'price', 'description', 'is_featured']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set source on value from [`Model.get_FOO_display()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) method

```
kind = serializers.CharField(source = 'get_kind_display')
```

Comment: Thank you this solution is better than mine.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this use fields source with get_FOO_display :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Product


class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    kind = serializers.CharField(source='get_kind_display')
    class Meta(object):
        model = Product
        fields = ('image', 'name', 'kind','price', 'description', 'is_featured')
```